# Loaded event and data-binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Suppose we have a control with a dependency property:

```
 public class MyControl : ContentControl
{

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }


    void DoSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...

    }

    public MyControl()
    {           
        this.Loaded += DoSomething;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, OnValueChanged));


    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some actions              
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyControl.ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyControl.ValueProperty, value); }
    }}
```

And somewhere in XAML we bind ValueProperty to some property Val of some ViewModel.

My question is, at the moment when Loaded event is fired, will the value of MyControl.Value be already set to the value of Val which it has or not? So, am I able to use Val in DoSomething method which is executed when MyControl is loaded or not?

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try it? ;)

Comment: I tried, and don't get what is wrong, in some cases it works (the value is set), in others it doesn't, I can't understand what it depends on, or I'm missing something, so I decided to ask whether there is any defined behaviour and what it depends on.

Comment: Please don't be mean, I'm just asking, I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out and debugging

Comment: I don't wanted to be mean but the information what you have already tried is important for someone who is trying to help.

Comment: I do not get the point why it should matter which value is set to Value. The value can be null, empty or some other string and it can change at any time. You must handle all of this values at any time. I can think of a small time span where you maybe have to handle it different: control is constructed but not yet loaded and the value changes.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, at the moment when `Loaded` event is fired, will the value of MyControl.Value be already set to the value of Val which it has or not?

You cannot rely on this. The `Loaded` event is not a 'data-binding-has-completed' event. Also, the value of a dependency property can change at any time and the place to handle any changes to your `Value` property is in the `OnValueChanged` callback. You could check whether the control has been loaded in the callback if you want to:

```
private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl ctrl = d as MyControl;
    if (ctrl.IsLoaded)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The point is that you should perform any action that depends upon the value of your dependency property in the callback and not in the `Loaded` event handler.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. In my situation the data is loaded from the ViewModel and it is to be checked for validity, in case the data is not valid, I need to perform additional actions. So I need to define a moment in time when all properties of my control are set appropriately in order to check it, I thought that when the control is loaded, that is the time when the properties are already set, because documentation says that when Loaded is fired, all binding is done (but nothing is said about them being set)... So now that Loaded can;t be relied on, I'm implementing this the other way

Comment: You could just set a boolean flag in each dependency property callback and then call a "Complete" method or something once all flags have been set.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {           
        this.Loaded += (s,e) => DoSomething();
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (MyControl)d;
        if ( c.IsLoaded )
            c.DoSomething();              
    }

    // this will be called only if the control is loaded
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        var value = Value;
        if ( value == null )
        {
            ...
        } else if ( value == string.Empty )
        {
            ...
        } else
        {
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, OnValueChanged));

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyControl.ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyControl.ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just needed to perform some data verification in order to perform certain actions before deciding what to show to the user when the control is loaded, so what I needed was precisely the moment before the control is shown, but all the properties are set already... I thought it could be after Loaded event.